# Getting value from CodeMirror fails

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I created an online editor using CodeMirror. My problem is that I'm failing when I try to get the value of the textarea.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
var code = $("#editor")[0];
var editor =  CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
  mode: {name: "pyhton",version: 2,
  singleLineStringErrors: false
},
  lineNumbers :true,
  indentUnit: 4,
  matchBrackets: true
});
```

and I'm trying to get the value with

```
 var value = editor.getValue();
```

I'm getting an error saying

> TypeError: editor.getValue is not a function